# In SpiderOak when creating a synchronization between folders, does the order of the two folders matter and if so how?

Tags: backup, sync

I want to use [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) to backup and synchronize folder across 2 computers (Comp1 and Comp2). From the instructions a back up must be made first and then the synchronization should be made, and I can see how that is a needed step as any folder that is not visible to the program first.

In my situation the files lay in a folder on `Comp1`, and I have backed up the folder. I create an analogous folder on `Comp2`, and perform back up on it to make it a visible on the SpiderOak network.

Now in step 2 of the `SYNC` process it asks to sync folder 1 with folder 2. Will this process merge the two folders? Will one overwrite the other? If there is overwrite is it the first or second folder that is overwritten? How does this apply to `Comp1` and `Comp2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for your setup is correct.  Create an empty folder on `Comp2` and then perform a backup to SpiderOak.  After this, setup the folder sync between the two folders.

According to SpiderOak's [FAQ](https://spideroak.com/faq/), [the most recently-modified version of the file](https://spideroak.com/faq/questions/48/which_version_has_priority_in_a_multiple_computer_sync_environment/) will be stored and synchronized.  Do not worry, though, because the older version will be saved as an historical version and will be accessible from the backup view.